# TradingView's 'end of line without continuation' error with Pine Script

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

Iam using this code in Pine Script but getting the "mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error.

How to fix that error with this function code?

```
//@version=3
 if study("My Script1")
```

Conversion, reason: Source pine is incorrect. line 5: mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: //@version=3
 if study("My Script1")

// Variables
 if entryPrice = close
 if exitPrice = 'close'
 if targetPrice = close + (high - low) * 0.5

// MACD
 if fastMA = 12
 if slowMA = 26
 if signalMA = 9
 if fastMA(src, fastMA)
 if slowMA(src, slowMA)
 if macd = fastMA - 'slowMA'
 if signalMA(macd, signalMA)

Comment: Please [edit] to update rather than commenting please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`study()` is a script type declaration statement. It returns `void`. Using it in an if statement makes no sense and wrong.

Also, if you want to check if some variable is equal to another variable, you should use the `==` comparison operator.